# How to clean a column with mixed variables like curreny in char format, blanks, strings in R

Tags: r, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

I have a dataset of startups, in which I have a column called "Amount" which is nothing but the valuations of each startup. when I tried to plot, the plot came out ugly and I found that those were in "char" format but when I tried to see the values in a column using `table(copy$Amount)` it showed all values mixed to each other. u can see the example pics here:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

I'm a beginner to R, I tried several small codes but nothing worked. I want to remove the "string rows", "blank row", and "empty $ symbol row without number" and convert the remaining rows into numbers.

Comment: Please use `dput` to show a small reproducible example instead of images

Comment: `readr::parse_number` should work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `parse_number` from the `readr` package, which:

> ...drops any non-numeric characters before or after the first number. The grouping mark specified by the locale is ignored inside the number.

For example:

```
> x <- c("1,000", "$1,000", "$$1,000", "1,000$")
> readr::parse_number(x)
[1] 1000 1000 1000 1000
```